# Get the sum of Column values based on date column (last date) and item name (unique item)

Tags: google-sheets

hope you can help with this.

I need to get the sum of values marked in yellow. The idea is to obtain the last registered value of each unique item in one month, and summarize all of them in one cell. The result must be 3.

Note: Date format shown dd/mm/yyyy

Here the data:

```
DATE        ITEM    VALUE
14/10/2020  ITEM1   1
22/10/2020  ITEM2   1
22/10/2020  ITEM3   1
23/10/2020  ITEM3   1
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rWQyB3bx0ql5M1lVYA88M9Ud23jDZKWKhpEieLxo9EU/edit#gid=582608434

Comment: So would you have several months in practice, and want to find the sum of the last values for each item per month?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use sort and sortn to remove duplicates occurring in each month, then group using Query:

```
=query(
      sortn(
            sort(
                  filter({year(A2:A),month(A2:A),A2:C},A2:A<>"")
             ,1,false,2,false)
       ,999,2,1,0,2,0,3,1)
,"select Col1,Col2,sum(Col5) group by Col1,Col2 label Col1 'Year',Col2 'Month', sum(Col5) 'Sum'")
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Please see below formula with two corrections, run on the same data as @marikamitsos:

```
=query(
      sortn(
            sort(
                  filter({year(A2:A),month(A2:A),A2:C},A2:A<>"")
             ,3,false)
       ,999,2,1,0,2,0,4,1)
,"select Col1,Col2,sum(Col5) group by Col1,Col2 label Col1 'Year',Col2 'Month', sum(Col5) 'Sum'")
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Here is the formula with an extra column:

```
=query(
      sortn(
            sort(
                  filter({year(A2:A),month(A2:A),A2:B,E2:E,G2:G,row(A2:A)},A2:A<>"")
             ,3,false,7,false)
       ,999,2,1,0,2,0,4,1,5,1)
,"select Col1,Col2,sum(Col6) group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col5 label Col1 'Year',Col2 'Month', sum(Col6) 'Sum'")
```

I wasn't sure what should happen when the same item falls twice on the same day, but clearly you want to keep the last one, so I have added the row number to the sort to achieve that.

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up. I tried comparing our formulas because I was getting different results from yours (yours were correct). So I touched the data more and believe I corrected my formula. But now [yours is off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfzyO.png). *I have to admit I was too lazy to find out how to tweak yours* :/

Comment: Oh dear! I thought it was just a simple mistake, that I had put 3 (date) insted of 4 (item) in the sortn, but there was another really stupid mistake where I should have put 3 (date) in the sort instead of just sorting on year (1) and month (2). Will edit my answer using your data

Comment: Thank you Tom! How can we add another filter column? lets say a "type" column, and use it to filter the summarize value. Hope i explained my self. I have the origin data with 4 columns: DATE, ITEM, TYPE, VALUE. And in another sheet or another place in the same sheet i have the first column with dates (jan 2020, feb 2020, etc), and the next columns are the TYPES (type1, type 2, etc). So i need to get the sum value form every month-year row and and type column. you can see the file, i added another sheet with this info.

Comment: I will add this to my answer. Quizas puedo mejorar mi Espanol en el mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

*(following OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611150/get-the-sum-of-column-values-based-on-date-column-last-date-and-item-name-uni#comment114267549_64612624))*

The previous formula works fine under unique dates. It is impossible though to distinguish between duplicate dates.

So, we create a unique virtual date by multiplying by row number of each date to get the desired results.

Please use

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP( 
                     QUERY({$A$2:$A*ROW($A$2:$A),$A$2:$G}, 
                               "select max(Col1) 
                                where month(Col2)="&MONTH($H2)-1&" and year(Col2)="&YEAR($H2)&" and Col6='"&I$1&"' 
                                group by Col3 
                                label max(Col1) '' "), 
                           {$A$2:$A*ROW($A$2:$A),$A$2:$G},8,0)))
```

[image]

---

**Original answer**

You mentioned

> ...obtain the last registered value of each unique item in one month, and summarize all of them in one cell.

Please try the following formula

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(INDEX( 
          QUERY(A2:C,"select max(A), B where month(A)="&E2-1&" group by B label max(A) '' ") 
             ,,1),A2:C,3,0)))
```

*(I have changed the data in your set so the formula can be easier understood. Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Comment: We agree now on your data - thanks for the heads up. You're going to hate me for this, but I think there might be an issue with yours when the latest date for two different items is the same and their values are different - e.g. try changing C8 to something else.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works perfect. I have another question. How can i use that formula to get te result in another spreadsheet, i mean, can i use importrange with that formula?

Comment: Sorry, i ran some test in my file and it doesnt work. I added a new sheet ("hoja 2") with data. I added new filter to the query formula to get the sum o values by date (last date), by unique item (GTIN) and by type (TIPO). But it didnt work. Im new using query formulas. Sorry to ask for your help again. Thank you so much.

Comment: *"You're going to hate me for this, but..."* Not likely @TomSharpe . Instead, thank you for pointing out the issue. Formula updated. Time to check yours :)

Comment: *"How can i use that formula to get te result in another spreadsheet, i mean, can i use importrange"* Of course. In any case. Why don't you try it? Also don't forget to check my updated formula